Orthonormality of Eigenstates of Quantum Fields Based on Simple Harmonic Oscillator
I first considered the Hamiltonian of the simple harmonic oscillator
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\hat{x}^2
$$
A position eigenstate $|x\rangle$ can be expressed in terms of the energy eigenstates $\{|n\rangle\}$ as follows:
$$
|x\rangle = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\langle n |x\rangle|n\rangle
$$
The coefficients $\langle n |x\rangle$ can be expressed as follows:
$$
\langle n |x\rangle = \bigg(\frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar}\bigg)^{1/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}}H_n\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}x\bigg) e^{-m\omega x^2/2\hbar}
$$
The above polynomials are Hermite polynomials. Since
$$
|n\rangle = \frac{(\hat{a}^\dagger)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|0\rangle
$$
we see that the position eigenstates are
$$
|x\rangle = \bigg(\frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar}\bigg)^{1/4}e^{-m\omega x^2/2\hbar}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}H_n\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}x\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\hat{a}^\dagger}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^n|0\rangle
$$
Using
$$
\exp(-z^2 + 2z\xi) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H_n(\xi)\frac{z^n}{n!}
$$
the position eigenstate becomes
$$
|x\rangle = \bigg(\frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar}\bigg)^{1/4}e^{-m\omega x^2/2\hbar} \exp\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{2m\omega}{\hbar}}x\hat{a}^\dagger -\frac{(\hat{a}^\dagger)^2}{2}\bigg)|0\rangle
$$
To find the momentum space eigenstates $|p\rangle$, we can use $\hat{x} = i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p}$ to rewrite the Hamiltonian as follows:
$$
\hat{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m^{'}}\partial_p^2 + \frac{1}{2}m^{'}\omega^2\hat{p}^2
$$
This is analogous to the above work and so by replacing $|x\rangle$ with $|p\rangle$ gives
$$
|p\rangle = \bigg(\frac{1}{m\omega\pi \hbar}\bigg)^{1/4}e^{-p^2/2\hbar m\omega} \exp\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{2}{m\omega\hbar}}p\hat{a}^\dagger -\frac{(\hat{a}^\dagger)^2}{2}\bigg)|0\rangle
$$
In Schwartz's textbook on Quantum Field Theory (chapter 14 on path integrals) he mentions the eigenstates and values of the real scalar quantum fields are
$$
\hat{\phi}(\vec{x})|\Phi\rangle = \Phi(\vec{x})|\Phi\rangle \text{   and    } \hat{\pi}(\vec{x})|\Pi\rangle = \Pi(\vec{x})|\Pi\rangle 
$$
I was thinking to make the following replacements in my formulas for $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$:
$$
x \to \Phi(\vec{x})
$$
$$
p \to \Pi(\vec{x})
$$
$$
|x\rangle \to |\Phi(\vec{x})\rangle
$$
$$
|p\rangle \to |\Pi(\vec{x})\rangle
$$
$$
\hat{a}^\dagger \to \hat{\phi}_+(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{a_p^\dagger}{2E_p}e^{ip^\mu x_\mu}
$$
$$
x^2 \to \int d^3\vec{x} \Phi(\vec{x})\Phi(\vec{x})
$$
$$
x a^\dagger \to \int d^3\vec{x} \Phi(\vec{x})\hat{\phi}_+(\vec{x})
$$
$$
x^\dagger a^\dagger \to \int d^3\vec{x} \hat{\phi}_+(\vec{x})\hat{\phi}_+(\vec{x})
$$
Similar for the other products found in the exponential operator in $|p\rangle$
To prove orthonormality of eigenstates, I want to show that
$$
\langle \Pi | \Phi\rangle = \exp\bigg[-i\int d^3\vec{x}\Phi(\vec{x})\Pi(\vec{x})\bigg]
$$
This is where I am stuck. I never get the exponent $-i\int d^3\vec{x}\Phi(\vec{x})\Pi(\vec{x})$. How do I show the above?

PSE would clearly be a better venue. Look at this, this, this, this...

Main idea.
The procedure behind the exercise of your textbook works as it follows. You can construct a (single-particle) creation operator $\hat{A}(x)$ for position eigenstates, whose action permits to create a position eigenstate $|x\rangle$ from the vacuum, i.e. $|x\rangle = \hat{A}(x)|0\rangle$. The same can be done with respect to momentum, hence an operator $\hat{B}(p)$ such that $|p\rangle = \hat{B}(p)|0\rangle$. Then, one has $\langle p|x \rangle = \langle0|\hat{B}(p)^\dagger\hat{A}(x)|0\rangle$ and the main point of the exercise turns out to be the normal ordering of the operator $\hat{B}(p)^\dagger\hat{A}(x)$ with the help of the BCH and Glauber formulas. In the end, a factor $e^{-ipx}$ will be produced by the said formulas, while the remaining factors will vanish when applied to the vacuum on the left and/or right. Finally, the same manipulations can be used mutatis mutandis when dealing with field operators, hence the desired result at the end.
About the "creation" operators $\hat{A}(x)$ and $\hat{B}(p)$.
You have derived partial expressions for the said operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ already, because the quantity $e^{x\hat{a}^\dagger-\frac{1}{2}\hat{a}^{\dagger2}}|0\rangle$ is indeed an eigenvector of the position operator, but it lacks a normalization factor, in such a way that the operator $\hat{A}(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\hat{a}^\dagger-x)^2}$ will generate the corresponding normalized eigenket of $\hat{x}$ from the vacuum actually. A similar expression can be derived for $\hat{B}(p)$, obviously.
However, several representations can be used for these operators, depending on whether one works with ladder operators or position/momentum operators, whether one works with a single or several exponential factors, letting aside the fact that expressions containing the annihilation operator $\hat{a}$ may be added almost ad libitum because it vanishes the vacuum $-$ but it might allow to "design" an easier expression for future computations.
Personally, I like the choices $\hat{A}(x) = e^{i\hat{p}x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\hat{p}^2}$ and $\hat{B}(p) = e^{-ip\hat{x}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\hat{x}^2}$, because 1° I find easier to work with hermitian operators, 2° the first exponentials can easily interpreted as displacement operators $-$ since translations are generated by the conjugate operator $-$, while 2° the exponential factors on the right create nothing else than the (already normalized) zero-eigenvalue eigenstates from the vacuum, while 3° the first exponentials can easily interpreted as displacement operators $-$ since translations are generated by the conjugate operator $-$, which map the said zero-eigenvalue ket to an eigenstate with another eigenvalue.
It is then straightforward to understand that the factor $e^{-ipx}$ will come from Glauber's formula applied to the displacement operators in the middle when trying to normal-order $\hat{B}(p)^\dagger\hat{A}(x)$. With regard to the latter normal ordering, you will realize quickly that the involved operators belong to the Lie group $SU(1,1)$ $-$ see this useful post, where some technicalities are discussed. You may find easily online "ready-to-use" formulas within references dealing with such normal ordering.
Another approach.
It is to be noted that the expression you want to prove for the inner product of momentum and position eigenstates can be derived in a more simple manner than suggested in your textbook. Indeed, as usually addressed in the case of single-particle operators, the momentum operator acts as a derivative with respect to the position eigenbasis because of Hamilton's equations.
Analogously, the momentum field operator will behave as a functional derivative when applied against the field eigenstates, i.e. $\hat{\pi}(\vec{x}) \equiv -i\frac{\delta}{\delta\Phi(\vec{x})}$. In consequence, the quantity $\langle\Phi(\vec{x})|\hat{\pi}(\vec{x})|\Pi(\vec{x})\rangle$ gives $\Pi(\vec{x})\langle\Phi(\vec{x})|\Pi(\vec{x})\rangle$ when $\hat{\pi}(\vec{x})$ acts on the right, while one obtains $-i\frac{\delta}{\delta\Phi(\vec{x})}\langle\Phi(\vec{x})|\Pi(\vec{x})\rangle$ when it acts on the left, hence a functional differential equation, namely
$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta\Phi(\vec{x})}\langle\Phi(\vec{x})|\Pi(\vec{x})\rangle = i\Pi(\vec{x})\langle\Phi(\vec{x})|\Pi(\vec{x})\rangle,
$$
which is solved by
$$
\langle\Phi(\vec{x})|\Pi(\vec{x})\rangle \propto \exp\left(i\int\mathrm{d}^3\vec{x}\; \Phi(\vec{x})\Pi(\vec{x})\right),
$$
as desired.
